# click function is not working in jquery if an alert function is not before it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, media-queries

i have created a preview playlist using ng-repeat, but click function on preview image is not working properly.
here is my HTML code:

```
   <div class="imgBox" ng-repeat="playlist in channelItems.slice(0,5)" ng-click="onPreviewClick($index)" id="imgFB{{$index}}">
                    <img id="preview" class="imgthumbnew" ng-src="{{playlist.ImageURL}}" data-item="{{playlist.MediaUrl}}" />
                    <span>
                        <label style="font-size: 12px; ">{{playlist.Title}}</label>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

here is my JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            //alert("clicked");
            setTimeout(function () {
            $(".imgthumbnew").click(function () {
                $("#mediaPlayerDiv").show();
                $("#thumbnail").hide();
                $("#media-video").attr({
                    "src": $(this).data("item"),
                    "autoplay": "autoplay",
                    //"data-tag": "true"
                })
            })
            }, 500);
     });
```

Comment: check the scope of your DOM element. whether that is in scope or not

Comment: problem was with ajax request time,   @arun p Johny has sorted it out .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you approach of using angularjs and jQuery like this is not proper, use proper ng-click handler to register your click handler

```
<div class="imgBox" ng-repeat="playlist in channelItems.slice(0,5)" ng-click="onPreviewClick($index)" id="imgFB{{$index}}">
    <img id="preview" class="imgthumbnew" ng-src="{{playlist.ImageURL}}" ng-click="imgthumbnewclick()" />
    <span>
        <label style="font-size: 12px; ">{{playlist.Title}}</label>
    </span>
</div>
```

then

```
$scope.imgthumbnewclick = function (playlist) {
    $("#mediaPlayerDiv").show();
    $("#thumbnail").hide();
    $("#media-video").attr({
        "src": playlist.MediaUrl,
        "autoplay": "autoplay",
        //"data-tag": "true"
    })
}
```

---

Another solution is to use event delegation to support dynamic elements

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.imgthumbnew', function () {
        $("#mediaPlayerDiv").show();
        $("#thumbnail").hide();
        $("#media-video").attr({
            "src": $(this).data("item"),
                "autoplay": "autoplay",
            //"data-tag": "true"
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// you can call click event on id easily 
$(document).ready(function () {
        //alert("clicked");
        setTimeout(function () {
        $("#preview).click(function () { // use this line
        //$(".imgthumbnew").click(function () {
            $("#mediaPlayerDiv").show();
            $("#thumbnail").hide();
            $("#media-video").attr({
                "src": $(this).data("item"),
                "autoplay": "autoplay",
                //"data-tag": "true"
            })
        })
        }, 500);
 });
```

Comment: sorry it did not work at all, i already had tried it . problem is not with "ID" or "CLASS" .  @arun p Johny answered it well